# Create JWT token using PEM certificate in node

Tags: java, node.js, jwt, rsa, public-key

I need to convert a Java code to node.js.
The Java code reads a p12 file, retrieves a public key from it and creates a JWT token using the following code —

```
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.EncryptionMethod;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEAlgorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSADecrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSAEncrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.EncryptedJWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;
//
// ...
//
            JWTClaimsSet jwtClaims = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder().issuer(iss).subject(sub).
                    claim("usr", usr).claim("pwd", pwd).expirationTime(exp).notBeforeTime(nbf).issueTime(iat).jwtID(jti).build();

            // Request JWT encrypted with RSA-OAEP and 128-bit AES/GCM
            JWEHeader header = new JWEHeader(JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, EncryptionMethod.A128GCM);

            // Create the encrypted JWT object
            EncryptedJWT jwt = new EncryptedJWT(header, jwtClaims);

            // Create an encrypter with the specified public RSA key
            RSAEncrypter encrypter = new RSAEncrypter((java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey) pubKey);

            // Do the actual encryption
            jwt.encrypt(encrypter);
```

The node.js code that I thought might help me achieve the same is —

```
const forge = require('node-forge');
const jose = require('jose');
//
// ...
//
        jwtString = await new jose.EncryptJWT({ usr, pwd })
            .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'RSA-OAEP', enc: 'A128GCM' })
            .setIssuedAt(iat)
            .setIssuer(iss)
            .setSubject(sub)
            .setExpirationTime(exp)
            .setNotBefore(nbf)
            .setJti(jti)
            .encrypt(pubKey);
```

When I pass the PEM public certificate to the encrypt method, it throws an error —

```
TypeError: Key must be of type KeyObject.
    at asymmetricTypeCheck (\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\lib\check_key_type.js:17:15)
    at checkKeyType (\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\lib\check_key_type.js:44:9)
    at encryptKeyManagement (\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\lib\encrypt_key_management.js:17:37)
    at FlattenedEncrypt.encrypt (\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\jwe\flattened\encrypt.js:109:96)
    at CompactEncrypt.encrypt (\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\jwe\compact\encrypt.js:26:43)
    at EncryptJWT.encrypt (\node_modules\jose\dist\node\cjs\jwt\encrypt.js:69:20)
```

If I try to convert the certificate to a key using `crypto.createPublicKey(pubKey, 'pem', null, 'utf8')`, I get this error —

```
TypeError: RSA-OAEP requires key modulusLength to be 2048 bits or larger
```

I understand that the key I am passing to the encrypt method isn't of sufficient length. Since the Java code reading the same certificate file runs but the node.js code doesn't, I am assuming the issue is with converting the key to a proper format. Any tips on how can I create a public key of sufficient length using the certificate?

Comment: Probably one of the involved NodeJS libraries does not support RSA keys smaller than 2048 bits (at least in the context of OAEP). RSA keys today must have a size of 2048 bits or larger for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The RSA key sizes allowed by the respective JOSE RFCs are at minimum 2048 bits.

That's it. Use a key of an appropriate bit length and you're set to go.